# Latest Android Studio Update - BROKEN

Tags: android, android-studio

Just updated to latest version of Android Studio via stable channel and upon launch facing the following exception:

```
Android SDK was installed to C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
Refresh Sources:
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources

Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 22, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
  Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Google Inc. API 22, revision 1'; it depends on 'Google APIs, Android API 22, revision 1' which was not installed.
  Done. Nothing was installed.
The following SDK components were not installed: sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-22 and addon-google_apis-google-22
Refresh Sources:
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources

Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 22, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
  Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Google Inc. API 22, revision 1'; it depends on 'Google APIs, Android API 22, revision 1' which was not installed.
  Done. Nothing was installed.
The following SDK components were not installed: sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-22 and addon-google_apis-google-22
```

Anyone know how to resolve this particular issue?

Comment: Launch SDK manager with admin privileges and install what's missing according to the error.

Comment: Whats confusing is that it already shows 'installed' in SDK mgr.

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall affected packages then.

Comment: Ok, I think its because I see 2 SDK folders. Android Studio seems to look in  \AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk and SDK mgr points to C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some tinkering around I noticed that I had 2 different Android SDK folders in c:/Users/[user_name]/AppData/Local/Android

1. /Android-SDK/
2. /SDK

I ran Android Studio on this machine since its beta v0.7 and so on, I believe the default SDK folder that AVD Manager downloads to was changed somewhere along the version progression of Android Studio.

And with v1.2 this problem came into the light, maybe for other folks version combination could be different.

But point of the story is: check your SDK path.

Anyways, to resolve I decided to do a clean install:

- Completely Uninstalled of Android Studio & any of its components via Start/DefaultPrograms
- Quick disk & registry clean via CCleaner (I also use Registry Mechanic, very detailed scanner)
- Reboot
- Fresh install of Android Studio

All is well after this.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

- Choose the new UI Design >> next
- Just try to cancel the "Downloading Components" from upper right
  corner 'X' button.
- A dialog box will appear then click OK (wait a bit for first time launch)

Comment: This didnt show for me, I couldnt choose new UI design.

Comment: I had the same error as in your screenshot and this solved the problem for me. I don't understand why they couldn't simply offer to install the missing dependency; or why clicking "Finish" after canceling the update wouldn't launch Studio normally.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problems with installing  Android Studio because folder path

> C:/users/UserName/AppData

is invisible and read-only. I had some problem too. And after i had done my AppData is visible, all gone perfect. So good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I just needed to have that sdk so I just looked it up and downloaded it straight from Here's [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools)
and it worked out great. no problems downloading from there instead.

Answer (score 0):

Select custom installation instead of standard installation ,and it is easy to use

Comment: Please provide steps or link for any tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Because 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' was not installed. You need to launch Android SDK manager via Terminal and install 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' before